# classpath reading in linux not working as expected

Tags: java, linux, spring, sh

I have used property reader as below

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

For windows i have used the below bat file which is working as expected

```
 echo off
    cd
    set classpath=../
    set classpath=%classpath%;../config
    set classpath=%classpath%;../lib/*
    cd 
    java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -cp %classpath% com.example.StartTransformer
    rem > till.log
    pause
```

Same thing i am trying in linux with the following shell script it is taking the inside jar property file instead of externalized property file

```
cd ../
home=$(pwd)
echo $home
classpath=
for i in `ls $home/lib/*.jar`
do
  classpath=${classpath}:${i}
done
PROPERTYFILE=$home/config/application.properties
classpath=${classpath}:${PROPERTYFILE}
export classpath=$classpath
echo $classpath
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -cp ${classpath} com.example.StartTransformer
```

Please tell me how to solve this issue in linux environment.

Comment: as you adding **all** jar files in a directory to your classpath, when not just add the `path`

Comment: I have tried keeping just paths in classpath still it is not working this time my main class is not working as expected
cd ../
home=$(pwd)
echo $home
classpath=$home/lib/
PROPERTYFILE=$home/config/
classpath=${classpath}:${PROPERTYFILE}
export classpath=$classpath
echo $classpath
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -cp ${classpath} com.example.StartTransformer

Comment: The path where `PROPERTYFILE` should be added to your classpath **not** the pathed filename

Comment: tried still not working.